# How to add MVC 5 View Page with (Layout Razor) on Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I started to learn `ASP.NET` and according [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view) tutorial i need to add Add, then click MVC 5 View Page with (Layout Razor):

[image]

The thing is that in my Visual studio 2013 i don't have this option of  `MVC 5 View Page with (Layout Razor)` inside add like in this exapmle.
this is what i have:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right clicking on Models instead of Views.  Try right clicking on Views if you need View add options.

Answer (score 4):

Right click your `Return View()` statement in the appropriate controller, and click `Add View`. Should be generated automagically.

By the way, and this is just my opinion, this seemed like a cumbersome way of adding views?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative from David's answer, if it's anything like other versions of Visual Studio, you can also right-click the name of the action in your controller and select `Add View...`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this video in youtube: Missing the ASP.NET Web Template option in Visual Studio

For me work: Using the installer from visual studio 2022 por example, Modify > Individual components > Select .NET Framework project and item templates and click Modify, and try again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this way , Rclick on your folder the Add>Newitem in Web you can search for Razor you will find all kind of Razor pages